# Configuring team project connections

Tags: tfs

I am setting up TFS 2012 Express.

I have restored the code into the databases from our previous server and went into the 'Team Project Collections' screen in TFS Server Express Administration Console.

I stopped the collection, edited it and saved it.  Now the screen is locked saying "Updating Project Collection Properties".  The only way I can stop it is to kill the console in the Task Manager.

However, if I do then when I rerun it the collection cannot be started unless I finish the config.  If I open, edit and try resaving it then I get the same progress bar with the caption "Updating Project Collection Properties" which does not ever seem to complete?

I have tried rebooting the PC but that has not changed anything.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: I have restarted `TFSJobAgent` service and my collection have been saved, mb that help you.

Answer (score 1):

If the properties don't have to be updated, find this table '*dbo.tbl_ServicingJobDetail*' in database '*Tfs_Configuration*', then remove the relevant data line which column '*Result*' is '*Null*'.

Another solution that has not be validated: try to check the user '*NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE*' on database 'Tfs_Configuration' whether or not to have the correct authority, then restart '*TFSJobAgent*' service.

——————————————————Seperator————————————————————

I tried, the first solution above is incorrect, the second is correct, try to check the '*NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE*' user is addin to the SQL Server instance.